# How should I set up privileges so that Apache can access my site's files?

Tags: permissions, apache2

I use Apache as Web-server for my site. My site is in `/home/reiji/Documents/native_project_2` folder. Now, folder `/home/reiji` have access rights equal `750`. With such rights `Apache` can't access to my site. I have executed `whoami` command to find out what user works behalf of Apache. Result is `www-data`. Then, I have added `www-data` user to `reiji` group, but after restarting of server my site is still not accessible.

In theory, when folder have access rights `750` (that is equals `drwxr-x---` where `r-x` is access rights of group) and I add user to group, folder of which belongs to - as user of group have rights to `read` and to `execute`, he must access to site's folder.

*Question:* **How can I set up access rights so that Apache could access to site's folder?**

P.S. Possibly, site's configurations may be needed.

```
<Directory /home/reiji/Documents/native_project_2>
        Require all granted     
</Directory>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/reiji/Documents/native_project_2
        FallbackResource /index.php
        ErrorLog /home/reiji/Documents/native_project_2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Of cource I have added it using `a2ensite`, and have restarted server.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you so desperately in urgent need of a total catastrophe, that you decided to take the shortest way by adding `www-data` as a member in your user's own group?! ... Please don't do that ... Alternatively, see ...

Comment: Please redesign your current setup: don't use /home but  put your site in  /www/html/ (or symlink that to a personal dir/partition/or /opt)( and not tp your home. Then add your user to the www-data group :)